# PickerView in Custom Keyboard

Tags: swift

I have a custom keyboard in an existing app that uses decimal place. I am trying to implement imperial measurements.

So I removed the decimal point from the keyboard and added a picker view where I would like to have all the possible fractions between 1/32 -> 31/32.
This is what it looks like right now. All functionality works with a UITextfield as expected, except the picker(above the "Done" button):
[image: Custom Keyboard]

I cannot get the [Strings] to load into the picker. The following is the protocol and custom class i have for the keyboard.

```
protocol imperialDelegate: class {
    func iKeyWasTapped(_ character: String)
    func iKeyDone()
    func iBackspace()
    func iKeyCalc()
    func iFraction()
}

class imperial: UIView, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
    
    var pickerData: [String] = [String]()
    
    let fractions = ["1/32","1/16","3/32","1/8","5/32","3/16","7/32","1/4","9/32",
                     "5/16","11/32","3/8","13/32","7/16", "15/32","1/2","17/32",
                     "9/16", "19/32","5/8","21/32","11/16", "23/32","6/8","25/32",
                     "13/16","27/32", "7/8","29/32","15/16","31/32"]
    
    // MARK:- keyboard initialization
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.dataSource = self
        initializeSubviews()
        picker.reloadAllComponents()
        picker.reloadInputViews()
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initializeSubviews()
    }
    
    func initializeSubviews() {
        let xibFileName = "imperialKeyboard"
        let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(xibFileName, owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView
        self.addSubview(view)
        view.frame = self.bounds
    }
    
    // MARK:- Button actions from .xib file
    
    @IBAction func keyTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.iKeyWasTapped(sender.titleLabel!.text!)
    }

    @IBAction func backspace(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.iBackspace()
    }

    @IBAction func Done(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.iKeyDone()
    }

    @IBAction func keyCalc(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.iKeyCalc()
    }
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return fractions.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return fractions[row]
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        self.delegate?.iFraction()
    } 
}
```

I call those protocol functions from another view that uses this keyboard in the UITextFields.

1. I want the picker to populate with the `[Fractions]`
2. I would like to understand how to store the string value that the picker is displaying into a variable in the viewcontroller that I am calling it from.

I don't have great understanding of the initialising which is where I imagine the issue is. Sorry for the dump of code.

Comment: I'm not saying this is your only issue, but I've found that a picker controller won't display if the text doesn't fit inside it.  Try using "32" and get that to display. Build up from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I worked out the display. It was just a matter of rearranging the code:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initializeSubviews()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initializeSubviews()

        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.dataSource = self
        picker.reloadAllComponents()
        picker.reloadInputViews()        
    }
```

I imagine the issue was that i was trying to populate it before it existed.

This is how I am fetching the value from the other view controller. First I edit the protocol to look like this so it requires an input of a string.

```
protocol imperialDelegate: class {
    func iKeyWasTapped(_ character: String)
    func iKeyDone()
    func iBackspace()
    func iKeyCalc()
    func iFraction(_ character: String)
}
```

Then the pickerview didSelectRow function looks like this:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    self.delegate?.iFraction(fractions[row])
}
```

And then all that was left was to call the function in the viewController so that the value on the custom keyboard could be sent the textfield like so:

```
func iFraction(_ character: String) {
    for tf in textFields {
        tf.insertText(character)
    }
}
```

So when you land on a value in the picker, the didSelectRow function sends the string to the protocol and this is then sent into the ViewController where it displays the value into the textfield.

This is how it looks.

[image]